# ArcGIS Schematics - Preventing overlapping links and consistent layout?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geometric-network, schematics

I'm trying to recreate some network diagrams on a consistent basis based on our geometric network data.

The layout algorithms I'm selecting are getting me close but I can't seem to fine tune the layout task to generate a consistent diagram with the desired layout.

This is the approximate style I'm looking to recreate. The important part is the roughly even distribution of the links / branches.

[image: Excel Drawing]

This is roughly what I have going (some of the time) when using the Schematic Editor.

[image: Network Cable with Notes]

- 1A / 1B: These are links that overlap that should not.
- 2: This is a link that need not extend to the right at all. It would great if it was just a straight link downwards.
- 3: This branch is an example of where better placement would be on the other side of the main line.

I used a Composite algorithm of the following tasks:

1. Orthogonal
2. Relative - Main Line (using a line attribute)
3. Geo - Rotate Nodes Along Links
4. Separate Overlapping Links
5. Square Links
6. Bypass Nodes

Anyone have a clue as how these tweaks can be achieved?

(This is cross-posted on [ESRI's Geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/187654-arcgis-schematics-preventing-overlapping-links-and-consistent-layout))